# Scraping every tabledata with scrapy

Tags: python, html, web, xpath, scrapy

**Introduction**

After working with scrapy for a couple of weeks now, i still have problems, to figure out, some xpath expressions.
Mostly i have big issues with extracting data of a table and  "ul and li" tags.

**Example**
Webpage i try to get data of:
https://www.karton.eu/460x310x160-mm-Postal-Shipping-Box

There is a table with is called: "Productdata" and i need every single line of, but i dont get any of it..
I tried something like:
`response.xpath('//*[@id="2"]/tr/td/text()').getall()`,
`response.xpath('//table[@class="table table-striped"]/tr/td/text()').getall()`

**My Code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import KartoneuItem
import csv

class KartoneuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "karton13"
    allowed_domains = ['karton.eu']
    with open("kartonsalllinks.csv","r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        start_urls = [items['Link'] for items in reader]
    
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse'),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-info-inner"]')

        if not card:
            print('No productlink', response.url)

        for a in card:

            items = KartoneuItem()
            items['SKU'] = a.xpath('.//span[@class="art_nr"]/strong/text()').get()
            items['Title'] = a.xpath('.//h1[@class="fn product-title"]/text()').get()
            items['Link'] = a.url
            items['Price'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="price_wrapper"]/strong/text()').get()
            items['Delivery_Status'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="col-lg-4"]/span/text()').get()
            items['Desc'] = a.xpath('.//*[@id="1"]/p/text()').getall()
            items['Breadcrumb'] = a.xpath('.//*[@id="breadcrumb"]/li/a/@href').getall()
            yield items
```

I already have a .csv file that contains every link of the domain, and now this code above, should open every link, check if its a productlink or not(`response.xpath('//div[@class="product-info-inner"]')`Pages without that tag, should be skipped because they could be categorylinks for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly output the keys with :

```
 response.xpath('//table[@class="table table-striped"]//tr/td[1]/text()[normalize-space()]').getall()
```

Output :

```
['internal dimensions:',
 'external dimensions:',
 'girth:',
 'quality:',
 'weight:',
 'volume:',
 'pallet dimensions:',
 'piece(s) per pallet:',
 'carbon neutral']
```

For the values (be sure to use `/td[2]//text()` not `/td[2]/text()`) :

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="table table-striped"]//tr/td[2]//text()').getall()
```

Output :

```
['460 x 310 x 160 mm',
 '515 x 335 x 170 mm',
 '122,5 cm',
 'B-Welle 1.2',
 '0,48 kg',
 '22.82 l',
 '1230 x 800 x 1880 mm',
 '410',
 'ClimatePartner ID printed']
```

Comment: can you explain me that the difference between ```/td[2]//text() not /td[2]/text()``` a bit more? or where can i read about it?

Comment: Sure. `/td[2]//text()` means find all text next nodes descendant from the `td[2]` element.  `/td[2]//text()` means find all text next nodes child of the `td[2]` element. You have to use the first expression because the last text node (`ClimatePartner ID printed`) is not a child of the `/td[2]` element but a descendant. Its parent is an anchor element (`a rel="nofollow" title="Link zu ClimatePartner.com"...`). If you use  `/td[2]/text()`  you will get 8 text nodes whereas you need 9 (9 keys > 9 values). That's why you have to use  `/td[2]//text()` : to get 9 text nodes (9 values).

Comment: W3S is a great place to start with the basics : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

You missed a tbody in your XPATH selector, I'm not sure what your item fields are etc... here I've just grabbed all the product data in a list which you can either manipulate or you could use XPATH selectors to individually put the data into seperate item fields.

### Code Example

```
table_rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="table table-striped"]/tbody/tr/td/text()').getall() 
cleaned_table_rows = [a for a in table_rows if a != '\n']
```

### Output

```
['internal dimensions:', '460 x 310 x 160 mm', 'external dimensions:', '515 x 335 x 170 mm', 'girth:', '122,5 cm', 'quality:', 'B-Welle 1.2', 'weight:', '0,48 kg', 'volume:', '22.82 l', 'pallet dimensions:', '1230 x 800 x 1880 mm', 'piece(s) per pallet:', '410', 'carbon neutral']
```

### Explanation

You're XPATH selector was

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="table table-striped"]/tr/td/text()').getall()
```

When it should be

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="table table-striped"]/tbody/tr/td/text()').getall()
```

I've then used a list comprehension to clean up the list as the variable `table_rows` has multiple `\n` items.

Comment: hey @AaronS, i already tried the xpath with /tbody before i posted the question, but i had no idea how to get rid of the "\n\r\t " Where can i read about so formatting things like that?

Comment: If \n\r\t is at the start or end of a string, then strip('\n\r\t') will strip it. But sometimes you'll need to replace it using the replace string method. string.replace('\n\r\t',''), the second argument of the method being what you want to replace it with. These are examples of string methods, python docs has a huge list, but searching for common string methods will help. If the '\n' is in a list, then again multiple ways to achieve this, I just did a list comprehension to create a new list without any item with '\n' in it. Again reading up on list methods is key, there aren't that many.

Comment: thanks, i gonna check it out, i did not much with python yet.